# sql - create single query to get the values for the given criteria

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that will generate the following table.
I know the column names (that is start and end date of each column. These dates will vary based on the month/year. Also the number of columns will vary since some month may have 6 weeks).

The number of pools may also vary. There can be 'n' number of pools. So I have create a query for each pool(row) and for each week(column).
 Assume there are 3 pools(3 rows) and 5 weeks (5 columns), I may need to run 3*5=15 queries.
 Is there any way to create a single query to fix this?
Can anyone help me in fixing this?
I am stiil working on this..

```
--------------------------------------------------
row 0 | week1 | week2 | week3  | week4  | week5  |
st-end|jan1 -2|jan 3-9|jan10-17|jan18-24|jan25-31|
--------------------------------------------------
pool a| 100   | 105   | 309    | 345    | 234    |
pool b| 106   | 108   | 399    | 245    | 214    |
pool c| 120   | 145   | 359    | 365    | 274    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, just a comment... This is generally the kind of situations in which I prefer to switch from SQL to imperative programming (Java). You could create a prepared statement that serves for calculating a generic "cell" and then execute it for each one of the 15 cells (by varying some parameter). There's nothing bad in it, and you're done in 15 minutes. If the computation and/or the queries are expensive, you can cache the resulting table. Doing all of this in SQL can become tricky and difficult to read/understand by others.

Comment: Without seeing the tables you're going to query in order to create the table (result set) you've shown it's impossible to say what the query should be.

Comment: @NickHolt - assume I trying to get the combination of ('pool a'- week1), (pool a - week 2), etc and this goes on all all pools and therefore 15 queries needs to be run I think. I just want to check if it is possible to run a single query..

Comment: This is called a _pivot_ query with dynamic columns.  This is currently not possible directly in MySQL.  See [this ink](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78) for some interesting workarounds.

Comment: @user1514499: trust me, go imperative. :) You can also run a script every 24 hours that updates a 'summary' table on the DBMS, if data has not to be real-time (and I believe this is the case)

Comment: If you have tens of summary tables like this you can consider creating a data warehouse supporting multidimensional querying.

Comment: I am  planning to get the number of weeks for a month of year first. Then I will run query on weekly basis basis (that is for loop each week and store it in a list of objects. so I need to run the query 6 times for 6 weeks and later display the data using displayTag. I think this should work better..

Comment: Which is imperative... :) However, if you need a large number of summary tables, really consider building a warehouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do it using CASE expressions? [See "Control Flow Functions"]
Something along these lines:

```
select POOL
      ,sum(case when dt between 20120101 and 20120107 then VAL else 0) as Wk1
      ,sum(case when dt between 20120108 and 20120114 then VAL else 0) as Wk2
    ...  ...
from MY_TABLE
group by POOL
```